# Trying to redirect client to Google OAuth, getting 405 error

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, cors, google-oauth, http-status-code-405

I'm try to create a Web Service that connects to the Google Calendar API. In attempting to authorize my app, I have generated a url with necessary scopes. The problem is when I try to redirect the client to the generated url, I am getting a 405 error with the following message:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

For the most part I have been following this guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer using the node.js client library.

From what I understand, it seems that Google has not configured their server to accept cross origin requests, what I don't understand is how I am supposed to redirect my users to their authorization page if I cannot send a request from my domain.

Here's the relevant code:

```
export function authorize(req, res, callback): any {
  let auth = new googleAuth();
  let oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
  if (// Check if we have previously stored a token.) {
    oauth2Client.credentials = //get token;
    callback(oauth2Client);
  } else {
    //redirect to google authentication page
    let authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      state: '/',
      scope: SCOPES
    });
    res.redirect(authUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: A 405 means “method not allowed” and so in this context means the server doesn’t allow OPTIONS requests at all to the `authUrl` URL you’re trying to hit. I think it probably has nothing at all to do with whether the server accepts cross-origin requests or not—but you can confirm by using curl or postman or some other tool to send an OPTIONS request to that  `authUrl` URL and see what you get back. I bet you’re gonna get a 405.

Comment: Anyway, as long as that server is giving a 405 to OPTIONS requests, there‘s no way you’re going to be able to successfully access its responses from your frontend JavaScript code. You’ll need to make the request from your backend code instead. For OAuth-based services that’s seems to be pretty much always the case—you’re not going to be able to use XHR or the Fetch API to get responses from them that your frontend JavaScript code can access.

Comment: @sideshowbarker The OPTIONS request is a preflight request from the browser, not something that I am purposefully doing. You're right, I get the same problem using postman, but the 405 to OPTIONS requests is still a problem I'll have to navigate since I am making a CORS request, right? If I do request server side how does the user authenticate? For example, if the link from the google example it asks you to log in and grant access to the example's scope. I still need the users to log in/ grant my app access.

Comment: Sorry for the crap formatting, here's the link: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.metadata.readonly&
 access_type=offline&
 include_granted_scopes=true&
 state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
 redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Foauth2.example.com%2Fcallback&
 response_type=code&
 client_id=client_id

Comment: Yeah sorry for the brevity—I’m aware the OPTIONS request is a preflight from the browser. My point was, that’s exactly the problem, because the browser will never include any credentials in that OPTIONS request and not otherwise do any kind of authentication when making it. So for it to work with requests from frontend JavaScript code using XHR or Fetch, the server must not require authentication/credentials. But it does.

Comment: Anyway I see there’s a JavaScript example at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js that shows the way that Google actually supports using the API from within a Web application. And at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview#quickstarts I see links to a bunch of other supported ways for doing it in various backend runtimes/languages. It seems like the best way to get something working would be by using one of those supported examples as a starting pointing and changing it however you need in order to integrate it into your existing code

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when AJAX receives a 300 status code, the browser will automatically send another GET request to the returned location on behalf of the client. Even if I had gotten around my CORS issue I would have then had to manually load the html page myself since the request was made on behalf of the client. What I really want is for the browser to make the request to the auth uri.

So my solution to this problem is to detect redirects on the front end and have the browser issue a completely new GET request. Still seems like a work around so if anyone else has a better solution I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

If some one use React or similar SPA Framework to solve this problem related to OAuth 2 read this:

Do not redirect on the server side. Don not do this (node.js/express as backend example):

```
router.get('/go', errorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect(authenticationUrl);
})
);
```

DO THIS:

```
router.get('/go', errorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
        redirectUrl: 'https://google.com'
    })
})
);
```

And then on your frontend client, get the response and make redirect. Example:

```
getUrl = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await API.get(`/go`);
        window.location = res.data.redirectUrl;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Work in React. Checked!

Answer (score 0):

As per the flow, it is shown like Browser (APP) -> API (Server) -> Google auth  (redirection), It is a very common trail with Identity provider servers like AWS, Google Auth, etc.. as they never send an additional header of ALLOW ORIGIN that's why browser reject the request when it comes to the point of redirection

Now comes the workout solution.

1. The App domain (http://localhost:3000) should be added as a trusted domain at the IDP server
2. Request to API server for Auth initiation should be

   window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login-google';